# See the default or null options for a SQLLite table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

Using SQLLite, is it possible to see columns that can / can't be null or see the default values for them?

I'm deciding between MySQL or SQLLite for my development DB, and just noticed this. MySQL you can easily do DESC my_table. SQLLite, using SQLLite Database Browser you can do "Database Structure", but it doesn't show any information beyond type.

Comment: Also note 2 things: 1) it's "SQLite", not "SQLLite"; 2) SQLite Data Browser is not the only SQLite management application out there, other applications can show you more than just a datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about SQLite with Rails. In that case, during the creation of tables, you can do something like this:

`t.integer :foo :default => 0, :null => false`

Mix and match as necessary.